# duration of animation depends on height of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to slideDown the element and it's duration must depend from the height. for example if height is 2000px duration must be also 2000

this is my js

```
var element = document.getElementById('detail-'+thisID),
style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
content_height = style.getPropertyValue('height');
var height_js=parseInt(content_height, 10);
$('#wrap #detail-'+thisID).delay(700).slideDown(height_js);
```

am i on right way? if yes where is the mistake?

Comment: what u mean by mistake?

Comment: in the first line ,Is the id start with "#"?

Comment: when there is just this $('#wrap #detail-'+thisID).delay(700).slideDown(700); it's work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using jquery, you may use [jQuery.height](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
$('#wrap #detail-'+thisID).delay(700).slideDown($('#wrap #detail-'+thisID).height());
```

Also, in your code, you should use  simply `document.getElementById('detail-'+thisID')`, without trailing `#`, which is just a jquery selector used to identify that element should be searched by Id.